# Formatting dates to be able to Subtract them Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have two objects stored in an array populated from a .csv file, I'm trying to get to a point where i can subtract one from the other.

```
TEST1 System.String TEST1=20170408
Last Use NoteProperty System.String Last Use=2017-04-18 17:46:42
```

How can i format the last use into the same format as test 1 whilst also being able to subtract from each other?

I have tried the below

```
$dt_last_use =$_."Last Use".Split(' ') |Select -First 1
```

but i get this output from it

```
2016-12-29
```

My end goal is to be able to something like this

```
                    #$dt_last_use =$_."Last Use".Split(' ') |Select -First 1
                    #$today = get-date

                    #$diff = ( $today -$dt_last_use)
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: `$dt_last_use = [DateTime]$_."Last Use"`

Comment: Hi @PetSerAl this will give me the output like "20 April 2017 19:32:46" how can i then convert the TEST1 to be able to subtract from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the comments, you can do the Last Use date just by casting it as a `[datetime]` object. For the Test1 date you'd need to use the ParseExact method which allows you to define a [datetime format based on certain tokens](http://winpowershell.blogspot.co.uk/2006/09/systemdatetime-parseexact.html) to match the format in your text string:

```
$LastUse = "2017-04-18 17:46:42"
$dt_last_use = [datetime]$datestring

$Test1 = '20170408'
$dt_test1 = [DateTime]::ParseExact($Test1,"yyyyMMdd", $null)

$today = (get-date)

$difflastuse = $today - $dt_last_use
$difftest1 = $today - $dt_test1
```

Obviously adapt the `$LastUse` and `$Test1` variables to `$_."last use"` and `$_.test1` for your circumstance, the above is just a complete/verifiable example.